# Can i get facebook group wall posts , all of them via api

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am member of a Facebook group and I would like to archive all the wall posts made from day 1 until today.

Can this be done via API get all of them ? If yes and how ? (I would like to get Everything like Links, Photos, and likes, even comments made on each post.

Answer (score 6):

You should be able to obtain the wall posts via the GraphAPI at this URL:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/{OBJECT_ID}/feed?access_token=...
```

Replace `{OBJECT_ID}` with the ID for your group.

See the [Facebook Documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/group/) for more details.

Comment: GROUP_ID/feed does not seem to work now. it returns an empty data array for every public group I've tried. do you know about any changes regarding this request?